# A dataset with ~10 million rows

Tags: data-request, data-format

I am looking for a dataset with 10 millions of rows to analyze it. Actually to rework it into more usable format and come up with some interesting metrics for it. So there are two requirements:

1) ~10 million rows

2) "Interesting" data to build some metrics on it (like users per country, average temperature in month, average check and so on).

So the question is: where can I find such dataset? I found awesome-public-datasets repo on Github but looks like there is no any classification by data size/format there. If you have any ideas about relevant datasets and where I can find it it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

City bike shares will have about that number of records, and because there will be some geospatial data (latitude/longitude) along with timestamps, it's usually a fun topic to explore

- [GitHub list of city bike share data](https://github.com/BetaNYC/Bike-Share-Data-Best-Practices/wiki/Bike-Share-Data-Systems)
- Washington DC ([Capital Bikeshare](http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/system-data)) has quite a large bike share system
- Capital Bikeshare [CSV Column Descriptions](http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/trip-history-data)
- [Raw data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html) for Capital Bikeshare (by my estimate, 1 MB zipped is about 100k rows of CSV)

> Duration - Duration of trip
>
> Start date – Includes start date and time
>
> End date – Includes end date and time
>
> Start station – Includes starting station name and number
>
> End station – Includes ending station name and number
>
> Bike # - Includes ID number of bike used for the trip
>
> Member Type – Lists whether user was a Registered (annual or monthly) or
> Casual (1 to 5 day) member.

[image]

(photo source [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Capital_Bikeshare_station_outside_Eastern_Market_Metro.jpg))

Comment: Thank you! Datasets looks great. But I can't find description for fields from these files: https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html Maybe you have an idea where I can find it?

Comment: I added a link and the text with the column descriptions.

Comment: But looks like this description doesn't matches with actual data. Here is a sample from "2016-Q3-Trips-History-Data-1.csv": `115008,8/31/2016 23:40,8/31/2016 23:42,32000,Norfolk Ave & Fairmont St,32028,Norfolk & Rugby Ave,W20299,Registered` Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Forgot to take a look on the header. Thanks a lot!